# Why do I need to return a value in a Java method, even if I always throw an Exception?

Tags: java, exception

Why doesn't the following code compile:

```
    @Test
public boolean testException() throws MyException {
    try {
        System.out.println("Try some resource, which may throw an exception");
        return resource.getSomething();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logAndThrowSpecificException(e);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Clean up");
    }
}

private void logAndThrowSpecificException(Exception e) throws MyException {
    throw new MyException("Checked exception", e);
}
```

In IntelliJ it complains that I need to return a value from the last line of the testException() method, but as far as I can see there is no code path that will get to that point? What am I missing?

There are [similar questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945545/in-java-how-do-i-set-a-return-type-if-an-exception-occurs), but the best resolution I could find was to just put in a return null statement. There was no proper answer to why this was necessary.

Comment: FYI: Eclipse does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] *as far as I can see there is no code path that will get to that point? What am I missing?*

There is, in general, no way to tell if a certain path is possible or not (standard result, follows immediately from the halting problem).

Due to this, the compiler won't put much effort into analyzing such things. In fact it won't even bother looking outside the method currently being compiled, which is why you get the error in this case.

The specifics of what is regarded as reachable code is specified in the Java Language Specification in [Section 14.21 Unreachable Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.21). In fact, it would be a **direct violation of the specification** if a compiler compiled the code you provided.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect it does not know for certain that `logAndThrowSpecificException()` will always throw an exception, even though it has a very clear name as to its purpose, so it would be possible for the end of `testException()` to be reached.

Comment: It *can't* know for certain. It is possible to instrument the class and replace the implementation of `logAndThrowSpecificException` with one that does not (always) throw an exception at load time. Keyword: aspect oriented programming.

Comment: @user1252434 thank you, that was exactly the precise answer I was hoping for. Though you should write an answer for it, so that I can accept that rather than this one. I think that will be the most helpful for the next person looking for the same answer.

Comment: @user1252434, I'm not sure I follow your argument. It sounds like you're saying the compiler can't know that `logAndThrowSpecificException` will always throw an exception, because someone could change the method after the class has been compiled. I can give you numerous ways in which I can change the bytecode so that it doesn't conform to valid Java code. The reason the compiler gives an error in this case, is because the spec says it should, and the spec says it should because there's no way, in general, to solve this type of reachability problem.

Comment: @aioobe: In general, the legitimacy of one compiled function should not depend upon the code which exists in others.  If one could declare the return type of a function as "doesntReturn", and if such functions would refuse to compile if there were any code execution paths which didn't throw an exception, then a compiler could determine that statements following a call to such a function could never execute without having to examine the code within the function.  Such a feature might not be overly difficult to add to the language, but as yet the designers have not thought it worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it seems obvious that `logAndTrowSpecificException` always throws an exception, the compiler can't know that for certain. It is possible to instrument the class at load time and replace the implementation of the method with one that does not (always) throw an exception.

Keyword: aspect oriented programming.

Comment: So you're saying, "that the compiler needs to be careful because someone can rewrite logAndTrowSpecificException after the class has been compiled"? I can give you numerous ways in which I can rewrite a method so that the class file is invalid... even though javac compiled the class.

Comment: I'm not thinking about invalid bytecode here. When the compiler looks at the method declaration it only sees that it *may* throw an exception. If it looked into the method implementation is could see that this exception is always thrown unconditionally. But the method implementation can be changed after compiling and may actually return. This *can* happen at load time, the class loader *may* replace the method with an otherwise valid, but not always exception throwing implementation. E.g. a noop. One way to do it would be an aspect with an around advice.

Comment: The class loader can do what ever it likes when loading a class. Even changing the return type of a method. Still, that isn't taken into account by the compiler. You're argument doesn't make sense.